# Present SwiftUI view over UITabBar / UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am switching some screens of my app to use SwiftUI and now i have the structure as follows:

`window?.rootViewController` is a `UITabBarController` containing 1 `UIViewController` and 2 `UIHostingController`s (to be able to present SwiftUI views)

When i'm trying to present a SwiftUI view over another contained in UITabBarController it doesn't cover the UITabBar.

[image]

While I know how to get expected behavior in UIKit i am completely new to SwiftUI and can't solve this problem.

The structure and code i use are as follows:

**AppDelegate**

```
    func presentInitialVC() {
        if settings.firstLoad {
            showOnboarding()
        } else {
            let tabBar = initTabBar()
            window?.rootViewController = tabBar
        }
    }

    private func initTabBar() -> UITabBarController {
        let chatsViewController = {
            let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Explore", image: R.image.tabChats(), tag: 0)
            tabBarItem.selectedImage = R.image.tabChatsSelected()

            let view = ChatsView() // SwiftUI view
            let hostingVC = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
            hostingVC.tabBarItem = tabBarItem

            return hostingVC
        }()

        let hubViewController = {
            let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Hub", image: R.image.tabHub(), tag: 1)

            let view = HubMainView() // SwiftUI view
            let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
            vc.tabBarItem = tabBarItem

            return vc
        }()

        let settingsViewController = {
            let tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Settings", image: R.image.tabSettings(), tag: 2)
            tabBarItem.selectedImage = R.image.tabSettingsSelected()
            
            let vc = SettingsViewController()
            let navigationVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            navigationVC.tabBarItem = tabBarItem

            return navigationVC
        }()

        let tabBarController = UITabBarController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = R.color.buttonsColor()
        tabBarController.viewControllers = [chatsViewController, hubViewController, settingsViewController]
        return tabBarController
    }
```

**HubMainView + SharingRulesView**

```
struct HubMainView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel = HubMainViewModel()
    @State private var showSharingRules = false
    
    var body: some View {
        SharingRulesView(isPresented: showsSharingRules, onOkTapped: { showsSharingRules = false }) {
            ZStack {
                NavigationView {
                    ScrollView {
                        LazyVStack(spacing: 36) {
                            ForEach(mockedSections) { sectionViewModel in
                                HubSectionView(viewModel: sectionViewModel)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(24)
                        .toolbar {
                            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                                Text("Hub")
                                    .font(.system(size: 34, weight: .heavy))
                                    .padding(.leading, 7)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .background(Color.secondaryBg)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Container to add blur to the HubMainView and show some content
struct SharingRulesView<Content: View>: View {
    var isPresented: Bool
    @State var onOkTapped: VoidClosure
    var content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        if !isPresented {
            content()
        } else {
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                content()
                    .blur(radius: 3)
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.black)
                    .opacity(0.4)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                CustomButton(onTapped: onOkTapped, title: "Ok")
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 59)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only solution on my mind is to rewrite UITabBarController to SwiftUI view and present it from there.
Are there any other solutions?

Comment: You can create new UIWindow for and that display it over current window

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is that in order to show `SharingRulesView` it should be presented modally as a view controller over full screen not as a subview of `HubMainView`. Hosting view controller of `HubMainView` is in hierarchy of `UITabViewController`, so if you show something inside of `HubMainView` it will always be under tab bar.

Comment: so you're suggesting to present `SharingRulesView` as a `.fullscreenCover` without rewriting UITabBarController to SwiftUI?

Comment: Yes, you can do it like that for example

Comment: so it covers the tab bar but how could it be possible to blur content then? since any ViewModifier doesn't have access to superview

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how blur works. It is blurring content rendered below. It is not applied on each view separately.